# Require one of two optional arguments in pydantic model

Tags: python, pydantic

I am developing an flask restufl api using, among others, openapi3, which uses pydantic models for requests and responses. In one case I want to have a request model that can have either an id or a txt object set and, if one of these is set, fulfills some further conditions (e.g., `id > 0` and `len(txt) == 4`).

I tried to use [pydantic validators](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) to realize this condition. I came up with the working code below, however, the validator for `txt` is quite crowded.

I am wondering if there is a cleaner solution, which separates the validations of a.) `id`, b.) `txt`, and c.) the condition to have one of these two, but not both set?

```py
from typing import Optional, Any
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator, Field, ValidationError


class SomePath(BaseModel):

    id: Optional[int] = Field(
        default=None
    )
    txt: Optional[str] = Field(
        default=None
    )

    @validator('id')
    def check_id(cls, v):
        if int(v) <= 0:
            raise ValueError(
                f'{v} is not a valid id.'
            )
        return v

    @validator('txt', always=True)
    def check_txt(cls, v, values):
        if v is not None:
            if not len(v) == 4:
                raise ValueError(
                    f'{v} is not a valid txt.'
                )
            if 'id' in values and values['id'] is not None:
                raise ValueError(
                    'Set only id or txt.'
                ) 
            return v
        else:
            if 'id' in values and values['id'] is None:
                raise ValueError(
                    'Either id or txt must be set.'
                )
            return v


# Test cases
path = SomePath(id='1')
assert path.id == 1
assert path.txt is None

path = SomePath(txt='test')
assert path.id is None
assert path.txt == 'test'

try: 
    path = SomePath(id='-1')
except ValidationError as e:
    assert e.errors()[0]['msg'] == '-1 is not a valid id.'

try: 
    path = SomePath(txt='tes')
except ValidationError as e:
    assert e.errors()[0]['msg'] == 'tes is not a valid txt.'

try: 
    path = SomePath(txt='testt')
except ValidationError as e:
    assert e.errors()[0]['msg'] == 'testt is not a valid txt.'

try: 
    path = SomePath()
except ValidationError as e:
    assert e.errors()[0]['msg'] == 'Either id or txt must be set.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify it a little.

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, ValidationError, root_validator


class SomePath(BaseModel):

    id_: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, ge=0)
    txt: Optional[str] = Field(default=None, min_length=4, max_length=4)

    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True


    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def validate_xor(cls, values): # better name needed ;) 
        if sum([bool(v) for v in values.values()]) != 1:
            raise ValueError('Either id or txt must be set.')
        return values
```

Firstly, you can validate an integer for `id` and `txt` length by Field [arguments](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#field-customization):

1. The `ge=0` (greater or equal 0) is used to get your non-negative integer.
2. The `min_length` and `max_length` are used to get a 4 character length string.

You will receive a different error message, but in my opinion “ensure this value is greater than or equal to 0” is more precise than generic “v is not valid”
You can remove your `id_` validator. You don't need it any more.

To validate [xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) you can use [root_validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#root-validators) with a slightly simpler version.

You can also add [Model Config](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/):

```
    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True
```

to your class to prevent bypass validation with assignment after the `SomePath` instance was created.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to rework the model due to other reasons, but I could reuse the `root_validator` as well as the `xor` idea, which is very neat for checking if exactly one is `None`.